# How to run ./ commands on windows

Tags: windows, command-line

Anyone knows how to run a `./` command on Windows?
For example: `./my-file`

Or is possible to run it with CygWin? Because I'm getting lots of errors with it

Thanks

Comment: What kind of errors are you receiving? Please [edit] your post with all relevant details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run 'start my-file' OR 'start ./my-file'